# vdi and zero client suggestions

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vdi, thin-client

Hey all I am new to the VDI area and was thinking about a project for a customer that I have who has 2 pc registers and a small server that houses mySQL for the custom register program I made for them. However it's about 7 years old now and they need to upgrade to something faster.

Now I am thinking about just getting them touch screen monitors and a zero client to be able to log in RDP and also have the ability to use their USB devices (barcode scanners, receipt printer, etc).

I have been looking at VDI hosts but it's a little confusing and all but I would like for the VDI server to be off site since they have a business Internet connection from Comcast.

So to breakdown what advice I need:

- What kind of zero client would be fast enough not to "studder" any and be able to support max 1920x1080 and 4 USB connections.
- What VDI software should I get? I have access to any Microsoft program so would Microsoft multipoint server 2012?